# R - Cut non-zero values

Tags: r

I have a time series data in a data table format (let's say it has columns "date" and "y"), and I would like to cut the non-zero values of y into quartiles by date, so that each quartile gets the label 1-4, and the zero values to have a label of 0. So I know that if I just wanted to do this for all values of y, I would just run:

```
dt <- dt %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      mutate(quartile = cut(y, breaks = 4, labels = (1:4)))
```

But I can't figure out how to do it to get labels 0-4, with 0 allocated to 0-values of y, and 1-4 being the quartiles in the non-zero values.

Edit: To clarify, what I want to do is the following: for each date, I would like to divide the values of y in that date into 5 groups: 1) y=0, 2) bottom 25% of y (in that date), 3) 2nd 25% of y, 3) 3rd 25% of y, 4) the top 25% of y.

Edit 2:
So I have found 2 more solutions for this:

```
dt[,quartile := cut(y, quantile(dt[y>0]$y, probs = 0:4/4),
              labels = (1:4)), by = date]
```

and

```
dt %>%
    group_by(date) %>% 
    mutate(quartile = findInterval(y, quantile(dta[y>0]$y, 
                                                  probs= 0:4/4)))
```

But what both of these seem to do is to first calculate the break points for the entire data and then cut the data by date. But I want the break points to be calculated by date, since obs distribution can be different in different dates.

Comment: `cut` doesn't produce quartiles, but ranges of equal length,

Comment: right, which would be quaertiles. By definition cutting data into quartiles means cutting it into 4 ranges of equal length.

Comment: No, cutting into quartiles cuts into ranges of equal density (probability). For the uniform distribution this will be the same, but in general it isn't.

Comment: ok that doesn't answer my question at all. I would like to know how to cut the non-zero values of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the output of `quantile` to the breaks argument of `cut`. By default, `quantile` will produce quartile breaks.

```
x <- rpois(100,4)
table(x)
x
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 
 1  7 17 19 17 18 12  5  1  1  1  1 
cut(x,breaks=quantile(x),labels=1:4)
  [1] 2    2    2    1    2    1    1    2    3    3    1    4    1    4    1   
 [16] 2    4    2    4    2    3    1    4    1    2    2    1    1    2    2   
 [31] 1    2    2    3    4    1    4    2    2    1    2    4    4    3    1   
 [46] 3    1    1    3    3    2    4    2    2    1    2    2    4    1    1   
 [61] 1    2    2    4    4    3    3    2    1    1    3    2    3    2    3   
 [76] 2    4    2    <NA> 2    3    2    4    2    1    4    4    3    4    1   
 [91] 2    4    3    2    2    3    4    4    3    2   
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Note that the minimum value is excluded by default. If you want your ranges to be computed including zero, the zeros will be NA's and you can use this to your advantage and use `is.na` to treat this differently afterwards.

However, if you want to exclude the zero's before computing the breaks, you will need to reduce the minimum break value slightly to ensure all values are given a label. You can do this by using `quantile(x[x>0])-c(1e-10,rep(0,4))` for example. The zeros will again appear as NA's in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly not sure what you mean by "cutting the non-zero values of y into quartiles by date", and I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to ask.

If 'date' is an actual date column, and you mean, "the new variable 'quartile' should indicate what part of the year y occurred in, assuming y isn't 0, in which case it should be 0", I'd do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# create example
dt <- data.frame(y = c(0, 1, 3, 4), date = c("01-02-18", "01-06-18",
   "01-12-16", "01-04-17")) 

dt <- dt %>%
   ## change 'date' to an actual date
   mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>%
   ## extract the quarter
   mutate(quartile = quarter(date)) %>%
   ## replace all quarters with 0 where y was 0
   mutate(quartile = if_else(y == 0, 0, as.double(quartile)))`
```

EDIT: I think I understand the problem now. This is probably a little verbose, but I think it does what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- tibble(y = c(20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 40, 0), date = c("01-02-16",     
   "01-02-16", "01-02-16", "01-08-18", "01-08-18", "01-08-18", 
   "01-08-18"))

new_dt <- dt %>%
    # filter out all cases where y is greater than 0
    filter(y > 0) %>%
    # group by date
    group_by(date) %>%
    # cut the y values per date
    mutate(quartile = cut(y, breaks = 4, labels = c(1:4)))

dt <- dt %>%
    # take the original dt, add in the newly calculated quartiles
    full_join(new_dt, by = c("y", "date")) %>%
    # replace the NAs by 0
    mutate(quartile = ifelse (is.na(quartile), 0, quartile))
```

Comment: thanks! This wasn't quite what I was asking for though. I've edited my original message to clarify.